Whatever would the cached include except for the file pages?
Environment: a standby/idle running physical system with RHEL 6.9
Symptom:  We have done some dd tests in order to observe the change of the buffers/cached size in the free -m cmd. After we had cleaned up the buffers & cache, the buffers were just empty whereas the cached was still with 111MB. And then the cached had increased about nearly 60MB when we dd the block devices.
Notes:    We know that some storage metadatas e.g. superblocks would be stored in the buffers but not the caches
So my two sub-questions are the followings:

Why would the cached column size still have 111MB after cleaning up the buffers & cache?
Why would the cached column size "obviously" increase during the dd process with the block devices?

# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      23673      72973          0      21233        759
-/+ buffers/cache:       1680      94966
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646       1098      95547          0          0        111
-/+ buffers/cache:        986      95659
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 6
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0    340 97844368    872 114688    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0    340 97844496    872 114748    0    0     8     0 1046  282  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844496    872 114748    0    0     8     1 1041  245  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844656    872 114748    0    0     8     0 1043  248  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844656    872 114748    0    0     8     1 1038  255  0  0 100  0  0
 0  1    340 97844536    900 114728    0    0     0    88 1038  312  0  0 94  6  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646       1097      95548          0          0        111
-/+ buffers/cache:        984      95661
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 6
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0    340 97844032    924 114724    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0    340 97844256    924 114744    0    0     8     0 1051  240  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844320    924 114748    0    0     8     1 1040  262  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844192    924 114748    0    0     8     0 1085  387  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844320    924 114748    0    0     8     1 1042  278  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 97844336    948 114724    0    0     8    88 1050  382  0  0 100  0  0
# 
# 
# 
#   
# nohup dd if=/dev/mapper/vgroot-Lvopenv of=/dev/mapper/vgroot-test_d1 skip=1000 bs=512k &
[1] 31265
# nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'

# 
# 
# vmstat 1 6
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0    340 95727896 2003476 175072    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  1    340 95206576 2511252 175320    0    0 253704     1 2037 2228  0  7 86  7  0
 0  1    340 94687136 3017104 175248    0    0 252932     0 2028 2249  0  7 87  5  0
 1  0    340 94162088 3528332 175184    0    0 255748    13 2769 3694  0  7 88  5  0
 1  1    340 93647632 4029624 175316    0    0 250792    32 2090 2361  0  7 87  6  0
 0  1    340 93156560 4507884 175300    0    0 239060    53 3246 4805  0  7 84  9  0
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 16
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  1    340 91163136 6448656 175376    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  1    340 90679296 6918568 175328    0    0 235016    84 3089 4673  0  7 82 10  0
 1  0    340 90181824 7403024 175372    0    0 242312     1 1992 2139  0  7 81 12  0
 0  1    340 89652680 7918120 175352    0    0 257416     0 2052 2285  0  7 88  5  0
 0  1    340 89132208 8424744 174992    0    0 253448     1 2075 2370  0  7 87  5  0
 1  0    340 88643328 8900780 175212    0    0 238088     0 1988 2108  0  7 88  6  0
 0  1    340 88139840 9391552 175028    0    0 245132   109 3326 4918  0  7 85  8  0
 0  1    340 87653032 9865536 175032    0    0 236928    28 3286 4714  0  7 84  9  0
 1  0    340 87162032 10343672 175088    0    0 239168     1 1996 2135  0  7 88  6  0
 1  1    340 86628672 10862840 175244    0    0 259464     0 2062 2269  0  7 87  5  0
 0  1    340 86111256 11366648 175280    0    0 251912     1 2027 2203  0  7 88  5  0
 0  1    340 85647328 11818128 175116    0    0 225672    76 3178 4722  0  7 84  9  0
 1  0    340 85119456 12331920 175352    0    0 257036     1 2045 2266  0  7 88  5  0
 1  1    340 84605016 12832912 175108    0    0 250628     0 2023 2223  0  7 87  5  0
 0  1    340 84103872 13320768 175124    0    0 243976     1 1996 2143  0  7 87  6  0
 1  0    340 83574232 13836432 175068    0    0 257800     0 2055 2257  0  7 88  5  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      18136      78509          0      16535        171
-/+ buffers/cache:       1430      95215
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      19348      77297          0      17714        171
-/+ buffers/cache:       1463      95182
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 8
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  1    340 76894032 20335952 175340    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  1    340 76765144 20462952 175320    0    0 63504 62141 2936 3832  0  3 83 13  0
 0  2    340 76542304 20675944 174984    0    0 106504 100072 4100 6171  0  5 86  9  0
 0  1    340 76384016 20831592 174540    0    0 77832 86633 3442 4367  0  5 74 21  0
 1  2    340 76203216 21006304 174852    0    0 87560 63616 3575 5025  0  4 80 16  0
 2  0    340 75999744 21205200 174716    0    0 99464 109757 4353 4825  0  6 69 25  0
 0  1    340 75887632 21317888 174624    0    0 56072 66444 2902 3058  0  4 67 30  0
 1  0    340 75776488 21427168 174860    0    0 54832 53877 2462 2719  0  3 86 11  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      23456      73190          0      21710        171
-/+ buffers/cache:       1574      95071
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 8
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  2    340 73209824 23919680 174788    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  3    340 73024896 24100928 175080    0    0 90640 58949 3819 4529  0  4 70 26  0
 1  2    340 72831408 24288564 174660    0    0 93972 116933 4019 5393  0  5 71 23  0
 0  5    340 72720272 24396836 175212    0    0 53980 48204 2674 3136  0  3 67 30  0
 0  1    340 72571424 24543292 174976    0    0 73224 114093 3475 3974  0  5 66 29  0
 0  1    340 72448096 24663100 174936    0    0 59912 62160 2826 3558  0  3 87 10  0
 2  0    340 72315760 24791336 174712    0    0 64264 64189 2990 3924  0  3 87 10  0
 1  0    340 72151496 24952988 175168    0    0 80784 80852 3604 4461  0  5 78 17  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      26734      69911          0      24901        170
-/+ buffers/cache:       1662      94983
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 8
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  1    340 64158176 32734544 175056    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 1  1    340 63928852 32954576 175112    0    0 110216 91508 4238 6208  0  5 79 16  0
 2  2    340 63731188 33147344 174416    0    0 96392 65021 4082 5205  0  5 69 27  0
 0  2    340 63559684 33315152 175000    0    0 83720 57344 3594 4304  0  4 73 23  0
 2  4    340 63375412 33494368 174696    0    0 89736 53849 3797 4833  0  4 60 37  0
 0  2    340 63287548 33580396 175388    0    0 42888 155148 2723 2397  0  5 74 21  0
 1  1    340 63205204 33662312 175368    0    0 41096 41445 2235 2548  0  2 75 23  0
 0  1    340 63015216 33847664 175244    0    0 92552 94760 3939 5725  0  5 78 18  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      36143      60502          0      34060        170
-/+ buffers/cache:       1912      94733
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 8
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  3    340 58571068 38169084 175056    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  1    340 58416972 38323708 174736    0    0 77320 99065 3467 3472  0  5 78 17  0
 0  3    340 58350100 38389268 175332    0    0 32776 29044 1946 2020  0  2 62 36  0
 0  1    340 58184636 38550036 175160    0    0 80392 78693 3303 4483  0  4 86 10  0
 0  1    340 58022008 38707732 175244    0    0 78856 82880 3281 4339  0  4 87 10  0
 0  1    340 57873524 38853140 175500    0    0 72712 70449 3134 4027  0  4 87 10  0
 0  1    340 57742212 38981140 175248    0    0 64008 62160 2847 3613  0  3 87 10  0
 0  1    340 57556304 39161388 174828    0    0 90120 91193 3542 4991  0  4 78 17  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      42214      54431          0      39966        171
-/+ buffers/cache:       2077      94568
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 
# 
[1]+  Done                    nohup dd if=/dev/mapper/vgroot-Lvopenv of=/dev/mapper/vgroot-test_d1 skip=1000 bs=512k
# 
# 
# 
# vmstat 1 8
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0    340 76560704 20466772 175368    1    1    61    22    0    0  1  0 99  0  0
 0  0    340 76560704 20466772 175368    0    0     8     1 1049  249  0  0 93  7  0
 0  0    340 76560688 20466772 175368    0    0     8     0 1086  393  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 76560432 20466796 175356    0    0     8    85 1053  387  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 76560720 20466796 175368    0    0     8   104 1060  256  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 76560720 20466796 175368    0    0     8     1 1052  249  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 76560856 20466796 175368    0    0     8     0 1042  242  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0    340 76560856 20466796 175368    0    0     8     1 1045  280  0  0 100  0  0
# 
# 
# 
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96646      21879      74766          0      19987        171
-/+ buffers/cache:       1721      94925
Swap:        16383          0      16383
# 
# 

